# Superlative: Correct way to use mix "most" and "-est" adjectives/adverbs?

Tags: superlative-degree

To create a superlative, when multiple adjectives/adverbs are preceded by most*, but the latter adjective/adverbs should normally be written with the *-est* suffix, which one of the two following forms is correct/recommended:

> The most incredible and easy path

vs.

> The most incredible and easiest path

Here, *easy* is meant as *easiest*, not just *easy*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are linking the two adjectives with *and*, the *most* applies to both and you have ended up with *most easiest,* which is incorrect. "The most incredible and easy path" is correct. While "most easy" is awkward, because it's combined by *and* with "incredible," it's not only acceptable but the only acceptable expression.

Because *most easy* is awkward to the point of being wrong, if you were to reverse the order of the adjectives you would need to move *most* as well:

> The easiest and most incredible path

To use *easiest* and keep *incredible* first, you need to eliminate the *and* so that the applicability of *most* is restricted:

> The most incredible, easiest path

Any other adjectives, where they easily form superlatives, must fit the same pattern:

> The most incredible, simplest, easiest path
>   The most incredible and simple, easiest path

Where an adjective doesn't form a superlative with *-est,* you have a choice:

> The most incredible, magical, simplest path
>   The most incredible and magical, simplest path
>   The most incredible, magical and simple path

Of these, the first is probably to be preferred.